# Style react-phone-input-2 material style with theme from MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-phone-number-input

I want to use react-phone-input-2 in my MUI application and it needs to match the look and feel of the other inputs I have in a form. All the other inputs inherit their styling from my MUI theme, however react-phone-input-2 does not. I have not been able to find a reasonable way to use theme styling on this input. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is what I tried:

```
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <PhoneInput
                inputClass='mega-test'
                
                inputProps={{
                  name: "phone",
                  required: true,
                  size: "small",
                  theme: { theme },
                  
                }}
                country={"us"}
                countryCodeEditable={false}
              />
            </ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the [react-international-phone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-international-phone) package instead.

You can find an example of use with Material UI [in docs](https://react-international-phone-docs.vercel.app/docs/Advanced%20Usage/useWithUiLibs).